# Расчёт количества выходных между датами

Tags: java, дата

подскажите пожалуйста.
Есть две даты - от и до. Нужно в этом промежутке посчитать кол-во выходных. При этом учитывать праздники, которые берутся из БД. Не понимаю как понять какой это день недели.

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужно узнать день недели в зависимости от даты, можете воспользоваться следующими примерами. Первый пример:

```
System.out.println("День недели: " 
          + new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE").format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())));
```

выведет день недели как строку:

> День недели: пятница

А следующий пример вернёт порядковый номер дня недели:

```
Calendar newCal = new GregorianCalendar();
newCal.set(2016, 9, 20, 0, 0, 0);
int day = newCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
System.out.println("Порядковый день недели: " + day);
```

и выведет

> Порядковый день недели: 5

Comment: Немного не пойму.  У меня задача посчитать кол-во выходных в промежутке двух дат. Эти даты вводит пользователь. Я взял ваш пример. Вместо цифр я подставляю данные что ввёл пользователь. Но проблема в том что показывает день недели 1(беру сегодняшнею дату). А в реальности это 5 день недели. Как получить реальный день недели?

Comment: У меня для сегодняшней даты как раз выводит 5. Возможно,  вам стоит проверить настройки часовых поясов на компьютере

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать метод:

```
LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.of(2016, 9, 3); //год, мес, день
LocalDate endDate = LocalDate.of(2016, 9, 10);
countWeekend(startDate, endDate); //результат будет = 2 (3 и 4 сентября этого года выходные)

int countWeekend(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate) {
    int weekdays = 0;
    if (startDate.isEqual(endDate)) {
        return weekdays;
    }

    while(startDate.isBefore(endDate)) {
        if (DayOfWeek.SATURDAY.equals(startDate.getDayOfWeek())
             || DayOfWeek.SUNDAY.equals(startDate.getDayOfWeek())) {
            weekdays++;
        }
        startDate = startDate.plusDays(1);
    }

    return weekdays;
}
```

Только обработайте пограничные условия, в этом примере дата начала будет учитывать выходной, а дата окончания нет.

UPD. для определения праздничных дней придется писать свои обертки, например создать enum, или попробовать найти подходящую библиотеку(Например, [Jollydays](http://jollyday.sourceforge.net/index.html))

Comment: тут будет всё из реальности? тобишь если я введу реальную дату, сегодняшнею, то покажет 5 день недели?